# See through dark overlay css and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm doing a site with a "hidden" image. I hide the image using a dark overlay, but now I want the cursor to see through the dark overlay.

An almost working example is here: https://jsfiddle.net/swx5x38j/

What I want to know is, how I make the light div look through the dark overlay div. Is this somehow possible, or should I go for different solution? And does some have a hint on such one?

The code follows here as well. First the CSS:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#image {
  background: url(https://placeimg.com/640/480/animals) center no-repeat;
  width: 800px;
  height: 600px;
}

#overlay {
  opacity: 0.9;
  background: #000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
}

#light {
  opacity: 1;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  background: #fff;
}
```

The jquery is as follow

```
    $(document).mousemove(function(event) {
    $('#light').offset({
        top: event.pageY - 50,
        left: event.pageX - 50
    });
});
```

And last the HTML

```
<div id="image"></div>
<div id="overlay"></div>
<div id="light"></div>
```

Comment: `pointer-events:none`.

Comment: you may use a hudge box shadow instead an overlay https://jsfiddle.net/swx5x38j/

Answer (score 5):

instead an overlay, you could use a box-shadow:

```js
$(document).mousemove(function(event) {
  $('#light').offset({
    top: event.pageY - 50,
    left: event.pageX - 50
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#image {
  background: url(https://placeimg.com/640/480/animals) center no-repeat;
  width: 800px;
  height: 600px;
}



#light {
  opacity: 1;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;box-shadow:0 0 0 3000px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="image"></div>
<div id="light"></div>
```

Comment: Of course! Thank you very much! I will work on with the box-shadow property.

Comment: I just realized that your solution doesn't work in Safari on mac. It's like the browser doesn't render the box-shadow correctyly because of the size. If I lower the size to around 1000px it works... Do you have an idea of how to handle this?

Comment: @Christian you need then, an overflow:hidden; if needed, then you can use an extra wrapper in fixed  or absolute position . give a try to this http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mVqrjq or http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bEYwxx

Comment: Thanks again. Your solutions don't fix the problem, though. Sorry, but thank you again. And please update, if you have other suggestions :) Everything is welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a fake image and calculate the offset of the background image like this:

CSS

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.image {
  background: url(https://placeimg.com/640/480/animals) center no-repeat;
}

#image {
  width: 800px;
  height: 600px;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
}

#overlay {
  opacity: 0.9;
  background: #000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
}

#fakeImage {
  position:absolute;
  width: 800px;
  height: 600px;
}

#light {
  opacity: 1;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="image" class="image"></div>
<div id="overlay"></div>

<div id="light" style="display:none;">
  <div id="fakeImage" class="image"></div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).mousemove(function(event) {
  $('#light').offset({
    top: event.pageY - 50,
    left: event.pageX - 50
  });
  var _top = (- $('#light').offset().top) + 'px';
  var _left = (- $('#light').offset().left) + 'px';

  $('#fakeImage').css({'top': _top, 'left': _left });

});
```

The random image required a unique class with the same image.

[JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/swx5x38j/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Add a massive border to the #light and add a negative margin:

https://jsfiddle.net/mpcmvej6/

```
.
```

And remove #overlay.
This method seems the most simple to me. 
The good part about this method is that there is no need to support box shadow and it does not require a second image element.

Another method is putting a copy of the image inside #light and move it in the opposite direction of #light.